# Generating function for sequence $\frac{(-1)^{n+1} B_n(x)}{n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, generating-functions

I wonder what is generating function for sequence $\frac{(-1)^{n+1} B_n(x)}{n}$.

Or, in other words, what is

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1} B_n(x) t^n}{n}$$

Mathematica fails to provide answer.

$B_n(x)$ are Bernoulli polynomials.

Comment: Do you mean $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty{\frac{(-1)^{n+1}B_n(x)}{n}}\frac{x^n}{n!}$$

Comment: @Eleven-Eleven no

Comment: I know that $$\frac{ze^{xz}}{e^z-1}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{B_k(x)}{k!}z^k,\quad |z|<1,x\in \Bbb C$$

Comment: I don't know of any ordinary generating functions of the Bernoulli polynomials, much less alternating sums of such.

Comment: You could simplify notationally since this is basically a logarithmic power series.  Many umbral arguments would denote the Bernoulli polymomials as $e^{B(x)t}$, so you could write yours as $\log(1+B(x)t)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we start from
$$\frac{e^{xz}}{e^z-1}=\frac{1}{z}+\sum_{k\geq 1}B_k(x)\frac{z^{k-1}}{k!}\tag{1} $$
we may replace $z$ with $-zt$ to get
$$ \frac{e^{(1-x)tz}}{1-e^{tz}}+\frac{1}{tz}=\sum_{k\geq 1}(-1)^{k-1} B_k(x)\frac{z^{k-1} t^{k-1}}{k!}\tag{2} $$
and derive the wanted series by multiplying both sides by $e^{-z}$ and applying $\int_{0}^{+\infty}\left(\ldots\right)\,dz$:
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}B_n(x)\frac{(-1)^{n+1} t^{n}}{n} = t\int_{0}^{+\infty}\left(\frac{e^{(1-x)tz}}{1-e^{tz}}+\frac{1}{tz}\right)e^{-z}\,dz.\tag{3} $$
By replacing $z$ with $\frac{w}{t}$ we get:
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}B_n(x)\frac{(-1)^{n+1} t^{n}}{n} = \int_{0}^{+\infty}\left(\frac{e^{(1-x)w}}{1-e^{w}}+\frac{1}{w}\right)e^{-w/t}\,dz.\tag{4} $$
The RHS of $(4)$ is a generalization of an integral defining the [Euler-Mascheroni constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant) $\gamma$.
By Frullani's theorem:

$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}B_n(x)\frac{(-1)^{n+1} t^{n}}{n} =\log(t)+\psi\left(x+\frac{1}{t}\right). \tag{5}$$